# jQuery calculator; subtraction trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a basic calculator for class (like Google's when you type in "calculator" in browser) and I'm currently stuck in the subtraction operation. Brief explaining: when I click #buttonless, a variable "num1" is stored, and then the "screen" goes to zero. Then, when I click #buttonequal, a variable "num2" is also stored, and from there jQuery subtracts both numbers.

The thing is, when I follow the result I am given with another subtraction, instead of subtracting the calculator sums both numbers.

```js
$("#buttonless").click(function(){
    var num1, num2, resultado;
    num1=parseFloat($("#screen").val());
    $("#screen").val(0);
    $("#buttonequal").click(function(){
        num2=parseFloat($("#screen").val());
        resultado=num1-num2;
        $("#screen").val(resultado);
        num1=0;
        num2=0;
    });
});
```

I've put an alert on bottom of the code and discovered that at the second time of subtracting (where the problem comes), the program subtracts 0, which seems to be "num1" at the time, to "num2", and then "num1" is replaced with the result I was given before, thus kind of "adding" the numbers.

For instance: I do the operation 3-1, and gives 2. But when I try to subtract 1 to that 2 (2-1) I'm given 3 instead of 1.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a demo for us?

Comment: You are defining one event handler inside another, thus causing a new event handler to be assigned every single time the first one is called. That can't be good.

Comment: @Goldenowner I tried to do an example on the second paragraph starting from the bottom.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I will try to remove the #buttonequal.click from there, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used an event handler inside another one. Try this:

```
var num1, num2, resultado;
$("#buttonless").click(function(){
        num1=parseFloat($("#screen").val());
        $("#screen").val(0);
});
$("#buttonequal").click(function(){
        num2=parseFloat($("#screen").val());
        resultado=num1-num2;
        $("#screen").val(resultado);
        num1=0;
        num2=0;
  });
```

If U can provide a demo, It would be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: I could solve it! It's close to your explanation, I had to remove #buttonequal.click from #buttonless.click, it's the answer on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on `#buttonless`, you create a new click handler for `#buttonequal`. So the second time around, that click handler will be called twice, once using the `num1` value from he first call (then putting the result in `#screen`), and a second time using the new `num1` value (and the result of the first subtraction, not the value you entered).

Either use `.once`, or set the click handler once only (i.e, not within the first click handler). In the latter case, you'll have the change the scope of the `num1` variable (and store the current operation, as you'll probably have more than just subtraction, I suppose).

Comment: Feel free to accept and/or up vote any answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for the feedback guys! I managed to finally do that in this way:

```
$("#buttonless").click(function(){
    resta=1;
    num1=parseFloat($("#screen").val());
    $("#screen").val(0);
});

$("#buttonequal").click(function(){
    num2=parseFloat($("#screen").val());
    if(suma==1){
        resultado=num1+num2;
    }
    else if(resta==1){
        resultado=num1-num2;
    }
    else if(multiplicacion==1){
        resultado=num1*num2
    }
    else if(division==1){
        resultado=num1/num2;
    }
    $("#screen").val(resultado);
});
```

Comment: This is a new question. Please ask a new question rather than posting it as an answer.